# Usar "OR" com tags na pesquisa de perguntas

Tags: suporte, perguntas, tags, busca

Ao entrar no Stack Overflow ele me exibe o feed das perguntas recentes ou ativas, contudo esta relacionado a todas as tags, assim para filtrar as perguntas que poderia vir a responder eu seleciono a tag especifica e ele me exibe apenas perguntas relacionadas aquela tag.

O que tentei e não consegui seria um `OR`.

Digamos que gostaria de responder perguntas feitas com a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) ou [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), assim pela logica eu tentei `[php],[java]`, `[php]|[java]`, `[php] or [java]`, mas não obtive o resultado esterado, que seria me retornar perguntas feitas com a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) ou a tag [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Este recurso existe?

Comment: Não entendi pq, mas a forma que você fez era para funcionar: `[php] or [java]` que daria a segunte url: **http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+java**. Aqui funciona normalmente.

Comment: De fato, funcionou no campo de pesquisa agora, eu estava tentando no de tags.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5230/198279 @Randrade

Comment: Eu não me lembro porque na época não traduzi a resposta pra cá, mas voltaram com esse assunto então me dei conta disso agora, antes tarde que nunca https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8470/3635