# Como pesquisar por perguntas que tenham uma tag X OU uma tag Y?

Tags: suporte

Quando quero responder perguntas sobre Python, preciso pesquisar primeiro por [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), depois por [python-2.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) e finalmente [python-3.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Mesmo que isso funcione, sempre tenho que ignorar as perguntas que já visualizei pois há perguntas com apenas 1 das tags, outras com apenas outra tag e também com as combinações delas.

Como não achei nada sobre isso no página de ajuda ["Como fazer uma busca?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), pergunto:

Como pesquisar perguntas que tenham uma tag **OU** outra?
Por exemplo, perguntas com uma das tags [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) e [python-3.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) ou ambas.

Comment: **NOTA:** graças a esta postagem detectamos que a página em português está desatualizada (não deveria ser necessário acessar a em inglês). Logo que resolvido, atualizamos o post. Até então, o link passado na resposta abaixo serve de paliativo. Grato por já trazer pergunta e resposta Fernando! Estamos precisando destas iniciativas. +1

Comment: Nossa, eu sempre escrevia direto a URL: `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-3.x` (que por sinal - descobri agora - é a URL resultante quando vc faz a busca usando OR)

Comment: @hkotsubo agora dá pra salvar o filtro e tirar dos favoritos do navegador..hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio eu sempre usei a  busca do firefox "sopt expressão", basta fazer o favorito com keyword e por um %s no placeholder. `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s` e  a keyword do bookmark eu usei "sopt"

Answer (score 9):

É possível pesquisar por tags utilizando OR, basta separar as tags com a palavra `or`.

Seguindo o exemplo da pergunta, bastaria pesquisar por:

```
[pyhon] or [python-3.x]
```

Também poodem ser encadeadas mais do que 2 tags, como:

```
[pyhon] or [python-2.x] or [python-3.x]
```

---

Encontrei a resposta para minha pergunta [nesta pergunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252743/1284458) do meta do SOEn, onde descobri que a [página de ajuda em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) contém esta informação na sessão *"OR Operator"*.

> **OR operator**
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": `[widgets] or [geegaws]` returns questions tagged with either tag.

Tradução livre:

> **Operador OR**
> Para combinar os resultados de múltiplas tags, separe os nomes das tags (que estão entre colchetes) com a palavra *"or"*: `[widgets] or [geegaws]` retorna perguntas que contém ambas as tags.

Answer (score 6):

### Busca por múltiplas tags

Um adendo, que eu já havia [comentado em 2015](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4453/usar-or-com-tags-na-pesquisa-de-perguntas#comment14115_4453), é que a busca por tags apenas também é possível, usando o "espaço" na URL, assim:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2B%2B%20c%23%20css%20html%20java%20javascript%20php%20python
```

A URL obviamente é codificada, o %20 indica o espaço, o %2B o sinal de + para o [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) e %23 o sinal de # para o [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), resultando em:

> [image: buscar por múltiplas tags]

---

### Ignorar tags (NOT)

Agora se a intenção for ignorar uma certa tag, supondo que algumas pergunta possam conter ambas, por usar o sinal -, assim:

> tagged/html -css
>
> Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html%20-css

Buscará todas perguntas de html, mas não pode conter a tag CSS

---

### Busca por tags usando wildcard/curinga

E também pode usar o caractere "curinga" para buscar que comecem ou terminem com certa string, exemplo:

> Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java~
>
> Resultando em:
>
> [image: busca por parte do nome da tag com caractere curinga]

O curinga também funciona no começo da string:

- [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~doc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%7Edoc)
- [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~ose](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%7Eose)

É importante notar que aparentemente a busca por curinga tem que ter no mínimo três caracteres, nos testes como [`/tagged/ja~`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ja%7E) ele desconsiderou.